# Excel - Advanced Filter with Dates

Tags: excel, filter

How can I get the '**Expected Result**' using Advanced Filters without having to create adicional columns?

[image]

**new picture**
[image]

With different date format it works with the criteria.

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a variation on your theme.

I have data very similar to yours (Date/Time columns).  I have formatted my filters to be date only (such as "<=01/01/2020").  I constructed a range so that I would expect several matches.  Sometimes I run the filter and get zero matches, and sometimes I get one match.

After reading your situation, I thought I would remove the time value from the first few rows of matching data.  Voila!  As a result, ALL matching lines are displayed, including lines with AND without a time component in the filter column.

It's always puzzling to get varying results to the same action, but I think for my purposes I can remove the time value from the data in order to make this work.

I know this is an old post, but maybe in the meantime you have more experience with the date filter.

Answer (score -1):

### Edited to clarify and reflect addition to OP

The Criteria in your first image would return nothing as both date/times are the same.  That would be equivalent to looking for values that equal `19/11/2018 00:00:00`. Since you have no entries exactly equal to that value, this will return no results.

However, it works when I change the right hand condition to `<=20/11/2018 00:00:00`.  This will filter on any value between `19/11/2018 00:00:00` and `20/11/2018 00:00:00` which gives your expected result.

OBTW, while I don't think date formatting is the problem, I did not validate your formatting on my sheet because I used my system default instead.

The reason it works in your second image is that now you are working with dates, not dates and times. Your criteria of `>=19/11/2018` and `<=19/11/2018` still equates to `=19/11/2018` but since you only have dates, all of the dates equal to `19/11/2018` meet the criteria. If you really want to filter on a date, not a range of dates, then you just need the one condition `=19/11/2018`.

Also, if additional columns are an issue, then you can filter in place with either the Advanced Filters or the AutoFilter without the need for additional columns for your output.  For AutoFilter, select `Date Filters` then `Custom Filter`.

Comment: Can you explain me new picture posted

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify and to address addition to OP.